# Python: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')"))

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using Tor to scrape particular website. It was scraping but now it is not working. My code which was working is.

```
def get_webContent_tor(url):
    with TorRequest(proxy_port=9050, ctrl_port=9051, password=None) as tr:
        ua1 = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
        ua2 = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome'
        headers = {'User-Agent': ua2,
                   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;' \
                             'q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}
        tr.reset_identity()
        tr.ctrl.signal('CLEARDNSCACHE')
        c = CookieJar()
        tr.session.cookies.update(c)
        resp = tr.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers,timeout=600)
    return resp.content
```

**Edit 1:** It is working then again not working. After 4 unsuccesful attempt it run once and when i run it again ,it is giving same error

Comment: If this code was working before then there’s every chance there is no problem with it and it’s much more likely the website you are trying to scrape is the problem. Did you try connecting to the website using a browser?

Comment: website is up it is working

Comment: Does your code work on a different URL? Without a URL that shows the problem, not sure anyone could answer your question

Comment: Yes it is working on different url .